# Sqlite file db for codeception testing fails

Tags: sqlite, symfony, codeception

Attempts to use a sqlite file database in the app/cache/tests directory fail. This is determined by clearing the dev MySQl database and populating the test environment database via the console.  Test database being populated was confirmed by an external Sqlite Manager.  [Tests performed without the sqlite configuration pass.]

#### codeception.yml:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: false
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        - Db:
            dsn: 'sqlite:./app/cache/test/test.sqlite'
            user: ''
            password: ''
            dump: tests/_data/test.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
            reconnect: true
```

#### Edit:

In an Ubuntu VM, adding the Symfony2 configuration to acceptance.yml allows for partial success - the test uses the Sqlite db but does not rewrite from the specified dump (test.sql).  In Windows adding the Symfony configuration makes no difference.

acceptance.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://vol
        - \Helper\Acceptance
# adding these lines enables Ubuntu to use sqlite db
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: ./app
            environment: test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't enabled Db module in acceptance.yml

`modules:
    enabled:
        - Db
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: http://vol
        - \Helper\Acceptance`

Also don't add PhpBrowser and Symfony2 at the same time,
only one can be used.

Comment: Fascinating.  I appreciate the insight.

Comment: I take it, though, that replacing Symfony2 config with a (working) WebDriver config in acceptance.yml is not sufficient.  Tests are performed against MySQL instead of Sqlite database

Comment: That's because your website uses mysql, Codeception has no control over application that it accesses via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I understand better now.

Comment: Sorry, but I remain somewhat stumped.  If WebDriver is used for acceptance test, and that test is performed against a live database, how is cleanup/rollback accomplished?

Comment: You have to configure codeception to use the same database as the site that you are testing. Don't test live website, deploy to another place for testing.

Comment: It all (almost) makes sense now.  Thanks for your patience and comments.